# Dividing json row data into multiple columns and store as a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

While reading data from JSON to pandas, a multi-criteria Value column is read as shown below.
Create a time series chart using the underlying data, containing any dimensions you deem to be appropriate/valuable.

First I imported data from sample URL with this code, so given  sample input data:

```
Code 

    import requests
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    response = requests.get('http://test1.com').json

Input:
JSON Data:
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://test1.com,"value":[
    {
      "Data":"28.00000000","Date_Code":"20200401","Date_ItemName_ENG":"1 Apr 2020","Date_SortOrder":"10","Date_ItemNotes_ENG":"","LocalHealthBoard_Code":"7A1","LocalHealthBoard_ItemName_ENG":"Betsi Cadwaladr University Local Health Board","LocalHealthBoard_SortOrder":"2","LocalHealthBoard_Hierarchy":"W92000004","LocalHealthBoard_ItemNotes_ENG":"","LocalHealthBoard_AltCode1":"W11000023","Hospitaltype_Code":"NHS","Hospitaltype_ItemName_ENG":"All NHS hospitals","Hospitaltype_SortOrder":"1","Hospitaltype_Hierarchy":"AllHosp","Hospitaltype_ItemNotes_ENG":"Includes data from acute hospitals only until 19 April 2020. Field hospitals data were added from 20 April 2020, community hospitals data were added from 23 April 2020, and mental health hospitals data were added from 10 July 2020.","Indicator_Code":"CO_Admissions_C19","Indicator_ItemName_ENG":"COVID-19 admissions (suspected and confirmed)","Indicator_SortOrder":"102","Indicator_Hierarchy":"Misc_Admissions_All","Indicator_ItemNotes_ENG":"Patients admitted as suspected or confirmed with COVID-19","RowKey":"0000000000000000","PartitionKey":""
    },{
      "Data":"28.00000000","Date_Code":"20200401","Date_ItemName_ENG":"1 Apr 2020","Date_SortOrder":"10","Date_ItemNotes_ENG":"","LocalHealthBoard_Code":"7A1","LocalHealthBoard_ItemName_ENG":"Betsi Cadwaladr University Local Health Board","LocalHealthBoard_SortOrder":"2","LocalHealthBoard_Hierarchy":"W92000004","LocalHealthBoard_ItemNotes_ENG":"","LocalHealthBoard_AltCode1":"W11000023","Hospitaltype_Code":"TotAcute","Hospitaltype_ItemName_ENG":"All Acute hospitals","Hospitaltype_SortOrder":"2","Hospitaltype_Hierarchy":"NHS","Hospitaltype_ItemNotes_ENG":"Prior to 10 July 2020, data may include small numbers of mental health unit beds.","Indicator_Code":"CO_Admissions_C19","Indicator_ItemName_ENG":"COVID-19 admissions (suspected and confirmed)","Indicator_SortOrder":"102","Indicator_Hierarchy":"Misc_Admissions_All","Indicator_ItemNotes_ENG":"Patients admitted as suspected or confirmed with COVID-19","RowKey":"0000000000000001","PartitionKey":""
    }


Needed output:
Data     Date_Code      Date_ItemName_ENG      Date_SortOrder    ................................

Solution Tried::::::
#####Tried Method 1#####################

    split = response['value'].values.tolist()
    rate = pd.DataFrame(split,columns =['Data', 'Date_Code','Date_ItemName_ENG','Date_SortOrder'])

Error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

#####Tried Method 2#########################

    data = json.loads(response)
    
    #print(json.dumps(data,indent=2))
    
    final_data = []
    for item in data['value']:
        my_dict = {}
        my_dict['Data'] = item['Data']
        my_dict['Date_Code'] = item['Date_Code']
        my_dict['Date_ItemName_ENG'] = item['Date_ItemName_ENG']
        my_dict['Date_SortOrder'] = item['Date_SortOrder']   
        print(my_dict)
        final_data.append(my_dict)
    back_json=json.dumps(final_data)

Note : Getting output in dict format not in different columns 
{'Data': '285.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '4.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '4.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '14.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '14.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '7.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}
{'Data': '7.00000000', 'Date_Code': '20200408', 'Date_ItemName_ENG': '8 Apr 2020', 'Date_SortOrder': '17'}

######Method 3#################################

    back_json=json.dumps(final_data)
    #df2 = pd.json_normalize(back_json)
    parsed_days = json_normalize(back_json)
    json_struct = json.loads(response.to_json(orient="records"))    
    df_flat = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_struct)

Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Please help tried all solutions but no way out
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand this correctly, you can directly get the desired output by using **final_data**
No use in using json.dumps since you already have a list that has series of dictionaries.

```
final_data = []
for item in data['value']:
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['Data'] = item['Data']
    my_dict['Date_Code'] = item['Date_Code']
    my_dict['Date_ItemName_ENG'] = item['Date_ItemName_ENG']
    my_dict['Date_SortOrder'] = item['Date_SortOrder']   
    print(my_dict)
    final_data.append(my_dict)

df= pd.DataFrame(final_data)
```

Comment: Thank You I got it into separate tables................. Just one more qt how to get the time series data part? Create a time series chart using the underlying data, containing any dimensions you deem to be appropriate/valuable.